# Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response. When I add custom post type

Tags: json, wordpress, plugins, themes, custom-post-type

I created custom post types in mu-foldername directory. Because of this custom post type I'm getting an error saying "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response." when I update or create default blog posts and even the images does not appears in the media library.

NOTE: I am using ACF plugin, my own custom theme and the plugin is updated to its latest version. There were no conflict between the theme and plugin and I am doing this in my local environment.

Is there any solutions for this?

[The error/warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4elV.png)

Below is my custom post type.

```
<?php
    function university_post_type() {
        //event post type
        register_post_type('event', array(
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events'),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Events',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Event',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Event',
                'all_items' => 'All Events',
                'singular_name' => 'Event'
            ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar'
        ));
        //program post
        register_post_type('program', array(
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'programs'),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Programs',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Program',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Program',
                'all_items' => 'All Programs',
                'singular_name' => 'Program'
            ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-awards',
        ));
        //professor post
        register_post_type('professor', array(
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'public' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Professors',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Professor',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Professor',
                'all_items' => 'All Professors',
                'singular_name' => 'Professor'
            ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more'
        ));
       
    }
   add_action('init', 'university_post_type');
?>
```

To resolve the above issue or find a way to move forward with the better path.

Answer (score 0):

But none of these were the reasons for my issue. **I had a line commented outside the php tag, that was the main culprit.** Now everything works fine after I removed that commented line. Such minor things caused major issue.